# How can I serve CGI scripts using perlbrew w/ Apache?

Tags: apache, perl, cgi, perlbrew

Error log:

```
[Tue Jun 17 12:08:35 2014] [error] [client 172.18.40.199] Perl v5.16.0 required--this is only v5.10.1, stopped at index.cgi line 2.
[Tue Jun 17 12:08:35 2014] [error] [client 172.18.40.199] BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at index.cgi line 2.
[Tue Jun 17 12:08:35 2014] [error] [client 172.18.40.199] Premature end of script headers: index.cgi
```

This is run as the user: 'support' and support runs perlbrew w/ switch set to 5.16.3 as shown below:

```
# su - support
print() on closed filehandle $fh at /loader/0x1cb94a8/App/perlbrew.pm line 19.
-bash-4.1$ perl -v

This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for x86_64-linux
```

What do I need to do to ensure Apache executes index.cgi w/ the perl installed by perlbrew?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS executes the interpreter identified by the shebang (`#!`) line of the script it was asked to execute (`index.cgi`). It's just a question of specifying the path to the interpreter you installed using `perlbrew` there.

Execute `which perl` (more familiar) or `perl -E'say $^X'` (more reliable?) to determine the value needed.

---

Let's do an example.

One on of my machines, I get the following when using my threaded build of 5.18.2. (You'll get something different.)

```
$ which perl
/home/ikegami/usr/perlbrew/perls/5.18.2t/bin/perl

$ perl -E'say $^X'
/home/ikegami/usr/perlbrew/perls/5.18.2t/bin/perl
```

So I'd use the following as the first line of `index.cgi`:

```
#!/home/ikegami/usr/perlbrew/perls/5.18.2t/bin/perl
```

Answer (score 2):

use a proper perl/bash shebang..

the following would work perfectly

```
#!/bin/bash
export PERLBREW_ROOT=/opt/perlbrew
export PERLBREW_HOME=/tmp/.perlbrew
export SHELL=/bin/bash #not really needed
unset XTERM_SHELL #not really needed
source ${PERLBREW_ROOT}/etc/bashrc
perlbrew use perl-5.21.9 > /dev/null 2>&1 # you can add your version here... 
eval 'exec perl -x -wS $0 ${1+"$@"}' if 0;
#! -*-perl-*-
# line 10 The above line/string resets the perldebug line-numbering... 
print "The perl interpretter running this code is $^X\n" ; 
print "This is perl version $^V\n" ; 
print "Hello PerlBrew \n" ;
die "This should be line number 14\n"  ; 
print "x\n" ;
```

That will result in...

```
The perl interpretter running this code is /opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.21.9/bin/perl5.21.9
This is perl version v5.21.9
Hello PerlBrew 
This should be line number 14
```

Hope this helps...

G

Answer (score 0):

Is there a shebang in index.cgi? Which perl does it point to?

I believe the shebang should point to your custom perl not the system perl that you have shown.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.16;
use strict;
use warnings;

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @vonbrand, The answer is not exactly high quality, but it does answer the question. Take the first paragraph as rhetorical questions.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/perl` is probably your system Perl.  Change that to `#!/path/to/perlbrew/perl`